# Nuxt generate returns 404 errors

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I've read multiple articles and posts about the `nuxt generate` issues, but i couldn't find an answer. So I'm learning Vue & Nuxt. I've create a spa, and i'm trying to host it on my website (in a subfolder eg. http://mywebsite.com/subfolder/). It's a simple hosting website (shared server) so i'd like to generate a static website from my files.

I'm running `nuxt generate` , but when i move the `dist` folder generated in my subfolder, i'm getting erros :

```
GET http://mywebsite.com/_nuxt/5f51d97c56209053356b.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
```

Of course, the path should be

```
http://mywebsite.com/subfolder/_nuxt/5f51d97c56209053356b.js
```

How can i fix this? From what i've understand, i should add some lines in my `nuxt.config.js` file right? I've tried multiple combinations, but i can't make it work..

Answer (score 5):

Allright so this was simple, i've finally found the answer [in the docs](https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-router#base). I've simply added in my `nuxt.config.js` file the following :

```
router: {
    base: '/subfolder/'
  }
```